# Pandas, accessing every nth element in nested array

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, pandas

I have a dataframe of many rows and 4 columns. Each column contains an array of 100 values.

My intuitive way of doing this is the same way I would do it with multi-dimensional numpy arrays.

For example, I want the first element of every array in `column1`. So I say

```py
df["column1"][:][0]
```

To me this makes sense: first select the column, then take every array, then take the first element of every array.

However, it just doesn't work at all. Instead, it simply spits out the entire array from `column1`, row 1.

But - and this is the most frustrating thing - if I say:

```py
df["column1"][1][0]
```

It gives me EXACTLY what I expect based on my expected logic, as in, I get the first element in the array in the second row in `column1`.

How can I get every nth element in every array in `column1`?

Comment: If it's a column of lists (or tuples) you can `df["column1"].str[0]` to select the first element of each list. But _really_ you might want to consider storing the data in a more flat 2D array

Comment: The reason your first selection doesn't work is because `df["column1"]` selects the **entire** Series, then [:] still selects the **entire** Series, so it didn't do anything, then Series[] is label based selection. So all that entire slicing does is to select Series, select all rows, then select the row labeled 0.

Comment: And to compare with your second selection `df["column1"][1][0]`, You select the entire Series, then select the row labeled `1`, at which point, given a non-duplicated Index, you have the value stored in that cell, which is a list, so your final selection returns the 0th element of that list.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `df["column1"][:][0]` isn't doing what you expect is that `df["column1"][:]` returns a Series. With a Series, using bracket indexing returns the item of the series at that index.

If you want to a series where each item in the series is the item in the corresponding array at that index, the correct solution - whether it seems intuitive or not - is to use `.str[...]` on the Series.

Instead of

```py
df["column1"][:][0]
```

use this:

```py
df["column1"].str[0]
```

It might seem like `.str` should only be used for actual `str` values, but a neat trick is that works for lists too.

Comment: Thanks! That actually works! Hallelujah! It's so counter intuitive to use .str on something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to do this:

```py
[item[0] for item in df['column1']]  # will result in a list
```

or

```py
df['column1'].apply(lambda item: item[0])  # will result in a series
```

Not sure if you're looking for a way that's similar to slicing, but AFAIU pandas sees the lists in your table are just arbitrary objects, not something pandas provides a sugar for.

Of course, you can do other fancy things by creating a data frame out of your column:

```py
pd.DataFrame(df['column1'].tolist())
```

And then do whatever you want with it.